# Why is Angular validation done in components/Forms not once on Domain Model?

Tags: angular, validation, business-rules, domain-model

I've come to Angular from a Grails background where you would define your business rules validation in one place against a domain model. GORM.... So when I've come to Angular, by way of Ionic, I'm surprised to not see something familiar. Am I missing something here? Is there a better way?

Comment: Isnt Grails a Java web framework? I cant see any relationship between the Java world and the Javascript world - or have I missed something

Comment: Well it's the decentralisation of validation that makes for duplication of effort that I'm trying to emphasise. Also you can have component 1 and component 2 having different rules eg 1 has a, b, c, 2 has a,b, d. Leads to a mess. And yes Grails is a full stack framework with Java/Spring/Hibernate under the covers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement validation in any case you want. Just add 1 more layer between angular forms and your domain.
In general, Angular doesn't dictate what way your application should work. It just gives you instruments for interacting with browser and APIs.

You always can implement `Domain#valid()` method and update fields via Reactive Forms.

```
@Component({})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

    public form: Form = this.fb.group({
        fName: ['', []],
        lName: ['', []]
    });

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((form) => {
            let entity: Entity = new Entity(form);
            let errors: ValidationErrors = entity.valid();
            if(errors.length){
                this.form.setErrors(errors);
                this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Entity/EntityError - what are these? I understand updateValueAndValidity from here https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl

Comment: That is just pseudo code. Entity - your own class, which could be `class UserEntity implements IEntity{}`, where `interface IEntity{ valid(): EntityError[]; }`. `EntityError` again is just abstraction/interface, that can be provided to Angular's form `setErrors()` method. Oops, updated code example, as I had typo there.

Comment: Right thanks. For others that's.. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setErrors  ... https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidationErrors -

Comment: In retrospect I think where this fails is the lack of easily doing something like existence checking in a generic fashion, or cardinality (0,1,n)  on the ends of referential constraints. GORM was a far superior solution in that respect.